# How to submit form with its native action URL on a button click in Angular js like j Query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I need to submit a form with it native action url using angular js  like  jquery,
In jquery we can submit the form like  this,What is the Equivalent code of below in Angular js 1.x? I know that  in angular js most of the form   submit in ajax but here i want to submit like below

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input  id="other" type="button" value="Go">
</form>
<script>
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can just use the standard js function `submit()` on the form's element

Comment: add `ng-submit` to the form and send GET/POST requests with `$http`, which will look like this: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2WR79jpbC73rEKeAZTGP?p=preview)

Comment: Hi,The actual problem is   i can't   use ajax in my Web app but  i use Angular js as validation   and the  form is submitted  through     action url for validation i use ng-disabled property it submit button so any validation is false then user can not submit the form  and if the user touch any of input controls or enter invalid email   then validation shows as ng-messages but  the user didn't touch the form and submit the form then i want to show all error messages for this  i used  ng-click="submitted=true" with out action url then all errors listed but with action url then form is submited

Comment: this form have multiple gallery image upload that's  why i not use $http.post()

Comment: For validations you should probably use below code:
<span ng-show="formName.elementname.$touched && formName.elementname.$error.required" style="color: red">Name is Required</span>

Comment: why can't you put $( "#target" ).submit(); inside ng-click.

Comment: Or else you have to create a directive to access the element and element.submit(); If the form doesn't seen to change. just add scope.$apply()

Comment: please check this,this is actually i need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625836/how-to-show-form-validation-error-message-in-angular-js-and-that-form-have-actio

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-submit` for the form and an `input type="submit"` to submit it:

```
<form id="target" name="target" ng-submit="go()" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" ng-model="form.myInput" required>
  <input  id="other" type="submit" value="Go" ng-disabled="target.$invalid">
</form>
```

You don't use `value` on input, you should use `ng-model` to link the input to your `$scope`.
The `submit` input is disabled is the form is invalid thanks to the directive `ng-disabled`. Since the first input is `required`, if it is empty, the button will be disabled. You can learn more on validators [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Here is a corresponding controller:

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.form.myInput = 'Hello there';

    $scope.go = function(){
        console.log($scope.form);
    }
}
```

As you can see, we the `ng-model` is linked to `$scope.form.myInput`

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pswyvzja/)

Comment: I used ng-disabled  but  validation errors are not shown there means   if validation is false then button is disabled but user  don't  know what are the validation errors  so  i cant use ng-disabled

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625836/how-to-show-form-validation-error-message-in-angular-js-and-that-form-have-actio

Comment: why don't you do the validation inside the function (here $scope.go) ? that would be the proper angularjs way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input  id="other" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {  
});
</script> 
</html>
```

Comment: I cant use  type="submit"   because i use a simple button  and call a validation function  on it ng-click

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625836/how-to-show-form-validation-error-message-in-angular-js-and-that-form-have-actio

Answer (score -1):

You may do it this way.

```
<form myform action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input  id="other" type="button" value="Go">
</form>

myApp.directive('myform', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr){
          element.find("#other").click(function(){
               element.submit();
           })
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This is one of the worst possible way to submit a form with angularjs. You should not use a directive on the form itself to submit it. There is already ng-submit to do it. Why use jQuery inside link function ?

Comment: @Groben He already told that he cannot use $http (in comments). So, a proper way or not, we have  get the requirement right.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625836/how-to-show-form-validation-error-message-in-angular-js-and-that-form-have-actio